# Can I make an IPA file for iOS devices that are not in the provisioning profile?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ipa

I found a way to make a ipa file:

> 1. Add necessary profiles and adjust build settings.
> 2. Set device as target to run the application.
> 3. Build the product.
> 4. Go to Products->yourAppName.app. Right click and show in finder.
> 5. Drag & drop to itunes profile and binary file.(drag it to Apps)
> 6. Select app in iTunes and right click to show in Finder. And there you can get the .ipa file.

But, the devices which are not in the development team can not install it?
Or, did I miss some configuration steps?
Do we have a way to solve this?

Comment: for all i know you can't do that. why not just add the needed devices to your provision profile?

Comment: You have to register them

Answer (score 2):

No this is NOT possible. The only way to install an app on a device without using the app store is with the ad-hoc method provided by apple, some info about this is [found here](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/distribute.html). For the ad-hoc method you will always need the UDID of the device you want the app to be installed on.

Answer (score 0):

You can also build the IPA the official way. Just create an ad-hoc provisioning profile, tell Xcode to use it for the Release build and choose Product → Archive. When the Organizer pops up with the app archive, choose Distribute and Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment. Then choose your identity and voila, you get the IPA.

But in either case the provisioning profile has to contain a list of all devices the app is supposed to run on, AFAIK there’s no official way around that.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of alternatives

You will need an "Enterprise Certificate" for your business. This allows you to install on any device. However Apple does not issue them lightly but if you are working for BigCorp LTD you might be able to get one.

Or use `TestFlight`  at www.testflightapp.com to distribute your build. Im not sure if thats predicated by you having a Enterprise cert in the first place. Check them out.

Comment: Although the Enterprise program always you to install apps on any device, you ar not allowed to distribute app to people who are not working for the company on which name the program is registered. It is only ment for employees.

Comment: TestFlight uses the ad-hoc distribution method, so it really brings nothing new to the table.

Comment: Testflight doesn't work without ad hoc certificate. Simply both of your options is not what OP needs

Comment: The OP was looking for a way to distribute outside the dev team. Enterprise cert will satisfy that requirement. I thought Testflight resigned the ipa with their own enterprise cert thus allowing distribution to any authorized device.

Answer (score 0):

I used to build .ipa package by the same method with you. But this kind of ipa WITHOUT provisioning profile in package, so it could be run only in iOS devices which has been jailbreak.